# What does "non-editable" mean for the privacy policy URL in Play Store

Tags: google-play

Context:

- We were using a link to a PDF version of our privacy policy before which is now rejected.
- We switched to a simple website page hosted by Wordpress which was accepted.

While updating our policies to another version (same page link) an I'm wondering if I'm breaking the **non-editable** requirement:

> Please add or update your privacy policy, and make sure it is available on an active URL (no PDFs), is **non-editable**, applies to your app, and specifically covers user privacy.

Do they mean with this:

A) Not a document which can be edited by the site visitor (e.g. Google Docs)

B) Not a web page which changes on privacy policy changes (i.e. link like /policy)

In case they mean A) I can just update the web page linked at `/policy`.

In case they mean B) I need to copy the web page and release a new version at `/policy-1.1.0`

**Answers**

Please provide a source if you answer the question, not just your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Console has an example which makes it sound like it's okay to have a static link which does not change when the policy itself changes:

> Enter a URL, for example https://example.com/privacy

They probably mean

A) just don't link a document which can be edited by the visitor.

*source: Play Store Console > select app > Policy and programmes > App content > Privacy policy > example below the input field for the URL.*